# how to pass input during executin of java code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I pass command line arguments to my java code in eclipse (and retrieve it using args[] in main method)-this is fine.

However, my scenario is different. My code periodically asks for input during execution. Where would I enter such input? when controls hits such input prompt, eclipse freezes

***EDIT***
Some of the answers I read below suggests using command line args or buffered reader or using console view: but my eclipse freezes right after asking me for sudo password (further, my situation is different from command line args as explained in the very first line).

I am using Kepler on centos 6.5

Comment: care to answer why this question was down voted (who ever did and if you know why you down voted)? Simple and straight forward question (though most of the answers are irrelevant to this question); this issue is preventing my app running in eclipse (every time I have to open eclipse in root made to avoid this , which is not the great solution)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puzzled why my question is down voted and why few respondents suggested irrelevant answer.
You can pass input using scanner or input stream if your code is expecting it. But my question is asking for uncertain situations(in this case, if my eclipse is started as sudo it wont ask for root password; but if I start as regular user it would ask for root password based on the Linux shell command that my java code has to exec)

Yes, you can pass the input to java code (executed under eclipse). From the command line window where eclipse was started, we can enter the input and java code can read it as string.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a console, its typically located at the bottom of your java perspective. If its not there just go to Window->Show View->Console.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Window -> Show View -> Console*. You will able to enter input.

For short cut , type : <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used an input stream reader or a buffered reader?

The following is a start on how

```
static InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(input);
```

Then you can use the buffered reader for taking input during execution.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass command line arguments from eclipse, run your program from eclipse as run on configuration it will open dialog box and click arguments tab and pass your arguments from there

Answer (score 0):

Use the Scanner class. You have to import it from java.util.Scanner;

```
String userInput;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter something: ");
userInput = input.nextLine();
```

and remember to close the scanner when you're done using it

```
input.close();
```